# html 3 rows layout with header and footer 100%

Tags: html, css

[There is my Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVBwo.png)

[image: [1]:]

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #F9FFCF;
}
#right {
  float: right;
  background-color: #00FFD3;
}
#nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  background-color: #FF0004;
}
#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
#main {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  background-color: #2200FF;
}
#footer {
  clear: both;
}
#content {
  width: 90%;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<div id="content">
  <nav id="nav"></nav>
  <main id="main"></main>
  <div id="right"></div>
  <footer id="footer"></footer>
</div>
```

I will have a background color in nav, in content and in right, and the height of all divs should be to the footer. How it this possible?

Comment: You should explain what you need in more detail.

Comment: With a great deal more HTML & CSS..

Comment: Please do some research. This question has been answered multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You'll get your layout

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #F9FFCF;
}

header{
    background-color:lightgreen;
    height: 20px;
}
#right {
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #00FFD3;
    height: 100px; // Used to show the layout
}
#nav {
    background-color: lightpink;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100px; // Used to show the layout
}
#main {
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    background-color: #2200FF;
    height: 100px; // Used to show the layout
}
#content {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#footer {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
    height: 20px; // Used to show the layout
}
```

```html
<header></header>

<div id="content">
  <nav id="nav">       </nav>
  <main id="main">     </main>
  <div id="right">     </div>
  <footer id="footer"> </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This this, its working well, hope this will resolve your issue.**

```
<div id="content">
  <nav id="nav">test nav</nav>
  <main id="main">main </main>
  <div id="right">right</div>
  <footer id="footer">footer</footer>
</div>

<style>
html,
body {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #F9FFCF;
  height:100%;
  min-height:100%;
}
#right {
  float: right;
  background-color: #00FFD3;
  height:100%;
width:20%;
}
#nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  background-color: #FF0004;
  height:100%;
width:20%;
}
#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
#main {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  background-color: #2200FF;
  height:100%;
width:50%;
}
#footer {
  clear: both;
}
#content {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height:100%;
}
</style>
```